# Forcing scroll of a div before scrolling body

Tags: html, css, scroll

I currently have two divs side by side. On page load the left div needs to take up 100% of the height of the window and have vertically central content. The content of the right div will be longer and will require scrolling. At the point the right div is fully scrolled, I want the body to begin scrolling to reveal the content below both divs.

This works fine when the cursor is on the right div, but when over the left div then the body scrolls rather than the right divs content. Can I use css to force scrolling of the right div prior to body scrolling or is this a job for js?

** Just realised there is also an ugly situation when trying to scroll back up again in which you get stuck in the scroll on the right div. GROAN. I'm thinking what I actually need is to stick the left div on scroll and release at the end of the container. What is the best solution for this? **

I started to look at sticky divs using jQuery Stickem which works in the way I want but i'm thinking is perhaps overkill for what surely can be achieved more simply.

I require a solution must work in all browsers including IE8+

```css
.top-content {position:relative; height:100vh}

.left-div {background-color:blue; float:left; width:35%; height:100%;}

.right-div {background-color:yellow; float:right; width:65%; height:100%; overflow:scroll;}

.bottom-contet {position:relative; background-color:pink; height:500px;}
```

```html
<div class="top-content">
 <div class="left-div">Currently, if the cursor is over the right div the page works as required. But if over this left div then the body scrolls straight to content below. I want it to always scoll the right div regardless of cursor position</div>    
    <div class="right-div">
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>

     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>

     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>

     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>

     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>

     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>

     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>

     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
        
     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>

     <p>scrolling right stuff</p>    
 </div>    
</div>   
      
<div class="bottom-contet">

    <p>content below</p>
        
     <p>content below</p>
        
     <p>content below</p>
        
     <p>content below</p>
        
     <p>content below</p>
        
     <p>content below</p>
        
     <p>content below</p>
        
     <p>content below</p>
        
     <p>content below</p>
        
     <p>content below</p>
      
</div>
```

All advice welcome, have found similar questions but none that fit quite what I want.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to listen to the scroll event of the right side div. Then you can check if it is fully scrolled (or close) using `element.scrollTop` along with the max scroll value. Initially you can set the `overflow-y` of the body to `hidden`. once you reached your desired scroll position for your inner div, you can change it to `overflow-y: scroll`. This change can be done via js/jquery.

You may also have to handle the reverse scenario. where user can go back to the initial state.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the scroll to the top-content div and fix the left div.
It should do the work.
You'll probably need to adjust some margins after.

Change your css to this:

```css
.top-content {position:relative; height:100%; overflow: scroll}

.left-div {background-color:blue; float:left; width:35%; height:100%; position: fixed}

.right-div {background-color:yellow; float:right; width:65%; height:100%; }

.bottom-contet {position:relative; background-color:pink; height:500px;}
```

Comment: @wf4 Thank you all for your responses on this. I guess I hadn't quite explained it properly, a stick div was really what was needed to get the 'bump' effect effect when the school ends. I have found a useful sticky div example but am struggling with width issue so have posted a new question. Will try and remove this one if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

First create a variable and set its value to `false` to indicate that the right window has not been scrolled down. When you scroll the page, we can check that variable, if its still false force the window to stay at the top. Once the right window has been scrolled right to the bottom, you can change that variable value to `true` which will stop the script that is forcing you back to the top and you will then be able to access the content below.

```js
//unable to scroll down by default
var rightScrolled = false; 
//when we scroll the page...
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    //check if we have scrolled the right window to the bottom
 if(rightScrolled == false) {
        //we haven't, force the window to remain at the top
       window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }

});

$(function($) {
    //when we scroll the right div...
    $('.right-div').on('scroll', function() {
        //check if we have reached the bottom
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            //if we have, set our variable to true
            rightScrolled = true;
        }
    })
});
```

```css
.top-content {position:relative; height:100vh}

    .left-div {background-color:blue; float:left; width:35%; height:100%;}

    .right-div {background-color:yellow; float:right; width:65%; height:100%; overflow:scroll;}

    .bottom-contet {position:relative; background-color:pink; height:500px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="top-content">
     <div class="left-div">Currently, if the cursor is over the right div the page works as required. But if over this left div then the body scrolls straight to content below. I want it to always scoll the right div regardless of cursor position</div>    
        <div class="right-div">
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>

         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>

         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>

         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>

         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>

         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>

         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>

         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>
            
         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>

         <p>scrolling right stuff</p>    
     </div>    
    </div>   
          
    <div class="bottom-contet">

        <p>content below</p>
            
         <p>content below</p>
            
         <p>content below</p>
            
         <p>content below</p>
            
         <p>content below</p>
            
         <p>content below</p>
            
         <p>content below</p>
            
         <p>content below</p>
            
         <p>content below</p>
            
         <p>content below</p>
          
    </div>
```